# What should one have in a dog pet first aid kit?

Tags: dogs, first-aid

I have ideas of what should be in such a kit; but I’m wanting to see if I’m missing anything important.

Thank you!
Chris

Answer (score 0):

Here’s what is on my list so far as part of a [blog article](https://petcareinsiders.com/2023/12/27/pet-first-aid-essentials-a-comprehensive-guide-for-every-pet-owner/). Before doing a bit of research, I didn't realize some human first aid items would cause problems for dogs. Do you have any suggestions that I missed?

- **Gauze Pads and Rolls**: For wrapping wounds or muzzling an injured pet.
- **Adhesive Tape**: Specifically for pets, as human adhesive tapes can irritate pet skin.
- **Cotton Balls or Swabs**: Useful for cleaning wounds or applying antiseptics.
- **Antiseptic Wipes or Solution**: To clean and disinfect wounds. Ensure it is pet safe.
- **Tweezers**: Handy for removing splinters or ticks.
- **Scissors with Blunt Ends**: To cut hair around wounds or trim bandages without harming the pet.
- **Disposable Gloves**: For your safety and to keep the wound clean.
- **Ice Pack**: Useful for reducing swelling from injuries.
- **Thermometer**: Preferably a digital one designed for pets.
- **Saline Solution**: To clean out wounds or eyes.
- **Blanket or Towel**: For wrapping your pet for warmth or restraint.
- **List of Emergency Phone Numbers**: Include your vet, the nearest emergency vet clinic, and poison control.